# How do I take string date input and convert it into another format?

Tags: python-3.x

inout takes in a date of type str in this format `"12-Dec-2015"` and returns another date of type str of this format `"Dec 12 2015"`. Note that the date may be a single digit – i.e. the input String is possibly `"1-Dec-2015"`.

How do I do this? I have tried searching but still cant get my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datetime.strptime` to parse the string as a `datetime` object and then use `datetime.strftime` to reformat it to a string.

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime("12-Dec-2015", '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%b %d %Y'))
```

This outputs:

```
Dec 12 2015
```

Please refer to [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for more details on `datetime` formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
s = "12-Dec-2015"
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d-%b-%Y").strftime("%b %d %Y"))

s = "1-Dec-2015"
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d-%b-%Y").strftime("%b %d %Y"))
```

**Output:**

```
Dec 12 2015
Dec 01 2015
```

- `strptime` to convert string to datetime object.
- `strftime` to convert datetime object to your required format in string.